# Comunicaciones en red mas allá de una IP o un Dominio

Tags: redes, ip, tcp

¿Es posible?

hablando de redes IP en general, e internet en particular, aun no estando limitado a estas, si no incluyendo también redes locales (a este lado del router)

existe alguna vía en la que dos procesos/maquinas/incluso virus se pueden comunicar que no sea a través de un nombre de dominio y una IP ??

y de cierta manera, el nombre de dominio se ha de convertir en IP a través de una resolución DNS

pregunto en el contexto de ciberseguridad y mecanismos que tienen los malwares apra comunicarse entre si, una forma es conociendo la IP del C&C o de la victima, y usar esta directamente. Y la otra por lo que veo, es "codificar" un dominio tipo xyxyxyxxyxyx.xyxyxy.tk y usar este de puente para la IP C&C o IP de la victima

Comment: No parece una pregunta con formato válido para [ask], te recomiendo además hacer el [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta corta es no. Dos procesos fuera de una misma máquina solo pueden comunicarse a través de direcciones IP.

Dos procesos dentro de una misma máquina no necesitan direcciones IP para comunicarse.

Dentro de una misma red es posible utilizar broadcasting para encontrar otras máquinas.

Hay que tener en cuenta que no hay diferencia entre tu red local y una red pública en cuanto a funcionamiento. La comunicación siempre va de tu PC al router. El router recibe a donde quieres ir y envía esa información al siguiente paso, que puede ser otro enrutador o la máquina de destino.

En tu red local lo mas seguro es que sea el segundo caso. Ya que cada máquina cuando se conecta a internet está enviando su información al router. Y por lo tanto el router lleva una tabla de las IP's locales que tiene registradas.

En cuanto a las DNS hay que tener en mente que no son mas un alias para una IP.
Cuando escribes google.com en el navegador tu router consulta una tabla y si ya tiene se dominio lo tendrá apuntando a una IP, y hace el proceso normal contra dicha IP.

Si no sabe resolverlo preguntará a los servidores DNS que tenga configurado para que lo resuelvan por el y lo guardará en un tabla para futuros usos.

En cuanto a los malwares específicamente, pues depende de cada programador como lo haya hecho y del objetivo del malware.

Si estás haciendo una red de bots lo mas normal es apuntar a una IP o una DNS. La ip tiene el inconveniente de que dejará de funcionar si usas otro servidor, por lo cual se suele optar por las DNS..

También pueden ser algo mas dinámicos, por ejemplo preguntar siempre a una IP específica pero esta le responde con un pool de ips con las que puede interactuar, y por lo tanto si uno cae puede probar otros etc...

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que podrías utilizar protocolos alternativos a IP que funcionen a nivel de capa 3.... pero ciertamente IPv4/IPv6 son los reyes a la hora de interconectar equipos. También creo que podrías desarrollar tu propio protocolo que se monte sobre algo de capa 2... pero estamos hablando de tener mucho (muuuuucho) tiempo libre para implementarlo. Adicionalmente, podrias hacer trucos con túneles ssh con lo que le podrias decirle a alguien: "utiliza el puerto X del propio equipo donde va a correr tu aplicación, yo me encargo de conectar con el equipo real al que te vas a conectar", con lo que te ahorrar el detalle de la IP. Podria haber más formas, ciertamente, pero son las que se me ocurren a vuelo de pájaro.

Answer (score -1):

Existen las MAC de los dispositivos y los paquetes IP que se mandan los routers (que supongo se podrán simular vía software) inundan la red con mensajes para que cada dispositivo conectado envíe su información y el router pueda tener sus tablas actualizadas.

Comment: No todos los dispositivos IP tienen dirección MAC. Por ejemplo, puedes conectarte vía modem telefónico. Los routers no "inundan" la red.